# program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception when using modulo in C

Tags: c, math, exception, modulo

I'm trying to make a program using C lang to calculate the given two numbers, A and B, how many numbers from A to B, inclusive, are divisible by another number K. For example, if A is 1, B is 10, and K is 3, then there are 3 numbers that satisfy this: 3, 6, and 9.

when trying to debug it in online compiler i get this error:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00005555555553fd in main () at main.c:346
346             int temp = j % newArr[j][2];
```

is there anything wrong in the modulo?

this is my current my attempt. i've tried this in`js` and it works, but not in `C`

```
int main(void)
{
  int arr[] = {100,16,9905,8,7346,...,301n]
  //the input is array 0f 301 integers, which the 
     first element is just the number of test case

  int newArr[100][3];
  int no = 1;
  int result = 0;
  int x, y, i, j;
  int start, end;

  for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
  {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
      newArr[x][y] = arr[no];
      no += 1;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    if (newArr[i][0] < newArr[i][1])
    {
      start = newArr[i][0];
      end = newArr[i][1];
    }
    else
    {
      start = newArr[i][1];
      end = newArr[i][0];
    }

    for (j = start; j <= end; j++)
    {
      int temp = j % newArr[j][2];

      if ( temp == 0)
      {
        result += 1;
      }

      printf(" %d result %d\n",i, result);
    }

    printf("case %d : %d \n", i, result);
    result = 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: If I read the code right you will set `newArr[0][0]` to the value `100`. Which will then be assigned to `end`. And then you use `for (j = start; j <= end; j++)` which will use the value `100` as an index into `newArr`. But `100` is out of bounds of `newArr`, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Continuing the previous comment, `newArr[1][1]` will be set to the value `7346` which is also out of bounds. So it's not enough to fix the condition of the loop `for (j = start; j <= end; j++)`, you must fix the values in `arr` as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `newArr[0][0]` actually set to `arr[1]`, because i declare the `no` to 1, sorry for the unclear code.

Comment: Okay, so you skipp `arr[0]`. Then you will set `newArr[0][1]` to the value `9905` and use that as an index into `newArr`. Which is still out of bounds, very much out of bounds.

Comment: i'm so sorry, turns out my only mistake was, in the `int temp = j % newArr[j][2];` which should be `int temp = j % newArr[i][2];` i mistaken the "i" with "j". because i'm iterating the first dimension of `newArr` and it works. Anyway, i'm not really catch up with the out of bounds problem, (maybe we can discuss more) i can only assume maybe this has to do with you mentioned `newArr` earlier and the problem turns out in the `newArr`. Thanks  for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical issue here: you have mixed up **i** and **j**

`int temp = j % newArr[j][2];`

should become

`int temp = j % newArr[i][2];`